# Fade in whole HTML page with function?

Tags: javascript, fade

What I want to achieve is to fade in a whole HTML page onclick, right now it just appears rapidly.

Here's what my code looks like right now, I click my div:

```
<a href="#" onclick="loadPage()">Hyperlink</a>
```

Which initializes a javascript function, that will then load my HTML page into this div:

```
<div id="pageContent"> </div>
```

Here's the function:

```
function loadPage()
{
    var fullHeight = window.screen.availHeight - 265;
    var objectOne = '<object style="width:100%;height:';
    var objectTwo = ';" type="text/html" data="test.html" ></object>'
    document.getElementById("pageContent").innerHTML=objectOne+fullHeight+"px"+objectTwo;
}
```

**Additional information:**
I am not familiar with the jQuery library yet, but I will accept a solution using it if it's described what happens in it, I want to learn.

Comment: Your function-name and onclick handler don't match.

Comment: Made a typo when entering the code just now, fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery makes things easy.

Add jQuery to page using

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Give your anchor an id

```
<a id="trigger" href="#" onclick="loadPage()">Hyperlink</a>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#trigger').click(function() { 
$('#pageContent').fadeIn();
});
```

(*NOTE* : Ensure that the Div is hidden on page load )

Comment: What do you mean "hidden"?

Comment: In CSS terms "display:none" on the content you are wanting to fade in. For the page to fade in, it must first be in a state of 'display:none' aka hidden from view. The jQuery function above will animate that state to a 'display:block' and you can control how long that transition takes by putting a time in milliseconds in the fadeIn function. Example $('#pageContent').fadeIn(1000) will fade-in in one second.

Answer (score 1):

here is jquery solution

http://jsfiddle.net/e4PZX/3/

this code do the trick:

```
$('#fadeIn').click(function() {
    $('#wholePage').fadeOut();
});
```